# file.save not saving file in proper format

Tags: python, flask

I have to upload a file on two places,

1. in a local directory
2. in Jira via curl

I have written `post` endpoint which read files from request and send same file to Jira over a request and after success response, it saves it locally.

my code looks like below

```
 for file in request.files.getlist('file'):
     filename = file.filename
     mimetype = file.content_type
     if not is_valid_type(mimetype):
       return json.dumps({"success": False, "message": "Invalid File Format" }), 415
     files = {'file': (filename, file, mimetype)}
     r = requests.post(jira_url, files=files, headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(current_app.config.get('username'), current_app.config.get('password')),verify=False)
     LOG.info("Got %s response from %s - text %s", r.status_code, "upload", r.json())
     data = r.json()
     filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
     file.save(os.path.join(current_app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"], filename))
```

it saves the file but when I try to open it, it says we don't support this file format.

if I remove the `post` call to Jira from loop then it saves the file in the proper format.

Comment: the post to jira call shouldn't affect the content of the files variable

Answer (score 0):

did you try with open/write?:

```
with open("input_file.txt", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write("destination_file")
    text_file.close()
```

solution to specify the path destination:

```
import os
filename = "input_file.txt"
path = "/pathlocation/..."
fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)
with open("input_file.txt", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(fullpath)
text_file.close()
```